# How to input an adjacency list?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, list-manipulation, input

I am a beginner user of Mathematica, and I have an assignment to construct a graph given n (number of vertices) and an adjacency list.

My idea was to make a For cycle that repeats n times, and for each vertex to input an array of adjacent vertices, but so far, I haven't found the right way.

Is there any way I can input the adjacency list using the function Input or something similar?

Comment: In what format is your input data?

Comment: I don't really have that defined, I guess it could be any way. (for example: just input the numbers of the adjacent vertices separated with commas)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: @DavidSimka If you don't already the data written down in some format, you should start by looking at the functions that you might want to work with an see what format is most suitable. Start to look at the graph functionality and see what format is used in the different examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdjacencyGraph[{{0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0}},
             VertexLabels -> "Name"]

[image]

If you wish to input the matrix interactively:

```
Print["number of vertexes"];
n = Input[];
a = Table[Input[], {i, 1, n}];
AdjacencyGraph[a, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

Then if, when prompted, you input $3$ for the number of vertexes, you'll be queried three times for the adjacency for successive vertexes.  If you input `{0,1,0}` then `{0,1,1}` then `{1,0,1}` (for instance), you'll get a directed graph with that connectivity.